# How can I get data from MVC Control's to CSHTML

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I apologize in advance for my mistakes, as I am new to the forum and .net

I'm working on an application using asp.net, c #, mvc5, EF6, db first

My problem is
I want to use a sql statement return in cshtml on the controller side, I cannot access variables that occur after the query in cshtml;

Thank you in advance to helpers

Conroller: OFISController.cs;

```
public ActionResult Index2()
{       sql = "SELECT * FROM OFIS o "
              + "left join OFISFIRMABAGLA ofb on ofb.OFID = o.OFID "
              + "left join FIRMA f on f.FID = ofb.FID";
    var qOFIS = db.Database.SqlQuery<DbSet>(sql);
    if (qOFIS == null) HttpNotFound();
   
   return View(qOFIS.ToList());

}
```

View: Index2.cshml;

```
@model IEnumerable<ildemavm3.Controllers.OFISsController>

...

<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.??????  )</td>
```

Comment: don't worry, just get a book for C# and MVC

Answer (score 1):

First create Model class for return result as per Query:
Example:

```
namespace ildemavm3.Models
{
    public class SampleData
    {
        public string Name {get; set;}
        public string Address{get; set;}
    }
}
```

Please note select Query must have same property name as Model class above

Controller: OFISController.cs;

```
public ActionResult Index2()
{
    sql = "SELECT **Name,Address** FROM OFIS o "
              + "left join OFISFIRMABAGLA ofb on ofb.OFID = o.OFID "
              + "left join FIRMA f on f.FID = ofb.FID";
    var qOFIS = db.Database.SqlQuery<SampleData>(sql);
    if (qOFIS == null) HttpNotFound();
   
    return View(qOFIS.ToList());

}
```

var qOFIS = db.Database.SqlQuery<**SampleData**>(sql);

Update Model class as above here I have created **SampleData** model class in starting

Change View: Index2.cshml as below;

```
@model IEnumerable<**ildemavm3.Models.SampleData**>
...
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.**Name** )</td>
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. but I have alot of sql script. I cant create a model class for eac one.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to pass data from MVC controller to the view. You can use viewData or viewBag which is a very handy and flexible option. You can pass multiple data at a time using this approach.